# is there a simple way to know which files will be updated in the next 'git pull'?

Tags: git, diff, pull, git-pull

i would like to know which files would be updated (and hopefully the changes that would occur) if i'd do a 'git pull'...

is

```
git stash 
git fetch
git diff origin/master
git stash apply
```

the answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/7/4/2350514). To quote:

> you can do a 'git fetch origin', then
>   a 'git log master..origin/master', and
>   it'll tell you what changes will be
>   merged if you do a 'git merge
>   origin/master'.

Comment: i guess also 'git log master...origin/master'

Answer (score 2):

Since `git pull` is `git fetch` plus `git merge`, do the `fetch` first, and then diff the remote branch against your current branch (`git diff origin/whatever..`).

Comment: Isn't that what he just said?

Answer (score 2):

> is
>
> ```
> git stash 
> git fetch
> git diff origin/master
> git stash apply
> ```
>
> the answer ?

Yes.