# How do I get the list of files about to be updated by `git pull` without knowing the branch name or what it tracks?

Tags: git

How do I get the list of files that are about to be updated (or were just updated) by `git pull` so i can parse them and take appropriate action in a script?

The accepted answer to [this similar looking question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284931/is-there-a-simple-way-to-know-which-files-will-be-updated-in-the-next-git-pull) showed me that I can get a list of commits with

```
git fetch && git log master..origin/master
```

but this is no good for me because I need a list of files, and my script cannot assume that the branch is `master` or that the current branch is tracking `origin/master`.

Through a little experimentation (and @Jonathan's comment), I have found that

```
git fetch && git diff master origin/master --name-only
```

is nearly there, but now I need to find a way to get the current branch and what it's tracking so that I can execute something like this (python):

```
"git fetch && git diff %s %s --stat" % (this_branch, tracked_branch)
```

I feel like I'm most of the way there, as now I only really need to know how to get the current branch and what it's tracking, but I've given a wider context in the hope that someone knows a much simpler way of solving this (`git incoming --files` would be nice ;)

Comment: For machine consumption, `--name-only` is probably better that `--stat`.  Besides not having to strip out the `| 72 ++--` at the end, it won't truncate file names with ellipses.

Not sure if that helps you with you actual problem, but I just though I'd point it out.

Comment: It definitely does help, thankyou :) I'll update the question.

Comment: @Jonathan: For machine consumption, if you want to know diff sizes, you use `--numstat` not `--stat`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you know the name of the remote (in my examples, origin) then you could simply go:

```
git fetch && git diff --name-only ..origin

templates/shows/showBase.html
templates/shows/showList.html
templates/shows/showListEntry.htm
```

Or if you wanted to sort into individual commits, you could use whatchanged:

```
git fetch && git whatchanged --name-only ..origin

commit fcb1b56d564fe85615ecd6befcd82f6fda5699ae
Author: Grambo <email@email>
Date:   Mon Dec 12 23:36:38 2011 +0000

    Hooked "I've Seen This" button up to "Review Show" dialog

templates/shows/showBase.html
templates/shows/showList.html
templates/shows/showListEntry.htm

commit xasdasdsada......
```

Comment: `git fetch && git diff --name-only ..origin` is exactly what I need :) I'm pretty sure that the remote will always be "origin" regardless of branch because everything gets cloned straight from bitbucket. Thankyou, accepted :)

Comment: `whatchanged --name-only` is pretty much equivalent to `log --name-only` (if there's a difference, I don't know it).

Comment: I ran the command as it is, on my local repository, while I am on master branch and master on remote repository is one version ahead. But I get this error - `fatal: ambiguous argument '..origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: I had to do `git diff --name-only ..origin/master`

Comment: Also, when the fetch actually happens, it shows some info, in addition to the file name changes. E.g. - `remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From <remote repository url>
   b2c98d5..9de3c78  master     -> origin/master
test/dummy.txt
`

Comment: @SandeepanNath You can use the `-q` or `--quiet` option of `git fetch` to show only the filenames of the modified files. The command would be `git fetch -q && git diff --name-only ..origin`

Comment: With `git fetch -q && git diff --name-only ..origin` I get `fatal: ambiguous argument '..origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` Adding `/master` to `..origin` - which results in `..origin/master` - it works.

Comment: I also get `fatal: ambiguous argument '..origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` with `git fetch && git diff --name-only ..origin` OR `git fetch && git diff --name-only ..origin/master`

Answer (score 13):

A more generic solution than @obmarg's answer is this:

```
git fetch && git diff --name-only @ @{u}
```

Here `@` is a shortcut for `HEAD` which in turn is a pointer to your currently checked out branch. `@{u}` or `@{upstream}` denotes the tracking branch for `HEAD`. So no hardcoded assumptions about the current branch (`master`), the name of the remote (`origin`) or the name of the tracking branch (`origin/master`) is necessary.

If you want to do this with another branch, use this:

```
git fetch && git diff --name-only master master@{u}
```

The syntax for `@{u}` is explained in `git help revisions`, search for `upstream`.