# XML_ERR_NAME_REQUIRED error on exec tag with git command in phing build xml file

Tags: git, phing

I am trying to put this command -

```
git fetch && git diff --name-only ..origin/master
```

in my phing build.xml file -

```
<exec command="git fetch && git diff --name-only ..origin/master" outputProperty="filesList" dir="${dir.destination}" />
```

But I am getting this error -

```
BUILD FAILED
/mnt/home/sandeepan/test_phing_build/build.xml:43:125: XML_ERR_NAME_REQUIRED
Total time: 0.1016 seconds
```

Line 43 of my build file contains the above mentioned exec tag.

I ran the git command manually in the specified location, and it runs fine. I guess I am missing something with the exec command. However, my build file contains other exec commands (with the same set of attributes - command/outputProperty/dir) which are working fine -

```
<exec command="git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD" outputProperty="box.branch" dir="${dir.destination}" />
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522692/351903

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid to use `&&` as an XML value. The parser thinks you're specifying a character entity.

A correct substitution for `&` would be `&amp;`:

```xml
<exec
    command="git fetch &amp;&amp; git diff --name-only ..origin/master"
    outputProperty="filesList"
    dir="${dir.destination}"
/>
```